# How can I make my images appear for an Image Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Create a JS image slider.
Guidelines:

- Include three or more images
- each image should: slide onto the screen, roll across (optional), and
  then slide off.
- Images should slide in a continuous loop.

```js
var filenames = ['image1.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'];
image0 = filenames[0];
image1 = filenames[1];
image2 = filenames[2];

var i = 0;


function enterLt() {

  var origWidth = 800;
  document.getElementById("container").style.width = origWidth;
  document.getElementById("container").style.left = 0;
  document.getElementById("container").style.margin = "0 0 0 -800px";

  var div = document.getElementById("container");
  div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + filenames[i] + '" id= "image1">';

  if (i < 2) {
    i = i + 1;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }

  document.getElementById("image1").style.width = origWidth;
  document.getElementById("image1").style.left = 0;
  document.getElementById("image1").style.margin = "0 0 0 0";

  var x2a = 0;
  var s1 = setInterval(moveIt, 5);

  function moveIt1() {
    x2a++;
    if (x2a >= origWidth) {
      clearInterval(s1)
      exitRT();
    }

    c = (0 - origWidth) + x2a;
    document.getElementById("container").style.margin = "0 0 0 " + c + "px";
  }

  function exitRT() {
    var origWidth = 800;
    document.getElementById("container").style.width = origWidth;
    document.getElementById("container").style.left = 0;
    document.getElementById("container").style.margin = "0 0 0 -800px";
    document.getElementById("image1").style.width = origWidth;
    document.getElementById("image1").style.left = 0;
    document.getElementById("image1").style.margin = "0 0 0 0";

    var x1 = origWidth;
    var x2b = 0;
    var s2 = setInterval(moveIt2, 5);

    function moveIt2() {
      x1--;
      x2b++;
      if (x1 < 0) {
        clearInterval(s2);
        enterLt();
        return;
      }

      document.getElementById("container").style.width = x1;
      document.getElementById("container").style.left = x2b;
    }
  }
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  margin-left: -800px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body bgcolor="linen" style="color:linen;" onLoad="javascript:enterLt()">

  <div class="a" id="container">
  </div>

</body>
```

This is my code for the image slider, but the images aren't appearing. I've added my image files, but the images are still not appearing. How can I get my images to appear?

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see whether you have any errors? The code you have shown gives me some JS errors on the console.

Comment: Yes, I have but I don't understand what it means. Can you help? Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
assignment2.html:95 Uncaught ReferenceError: enterLt is not defined
    at onload (assignment2.html:95:95)

Comment: I fixed the error. I was missing curly braces.